# Prism binding wrong viewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-store-apps, prism

I'm just arrived on a project in my firm (the kind of project which near fifty different people touch the code during the past year ...)

I'm trying to patch a few bug but I'm stuck with something.

We are using prism with a MVVM model.

I got a ContactDetailPage view that should be binded to ContactDetailPageVM with the following line in the xaml, am i wrong ?

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

Instead, and I've no idea why, it is binded to a VM called ProfilsPagesVM.

Anyone got a solution to force the binding on ContactDetailPageVM ?

Got through the net and didn't find anything relevant about my problem. Any link welcome.

To help you here's ContactDetailPageVM code :

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class ContactDetailPageVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        private Contact _selectedContact;
        public Contact SelectedContact
        {
            get { return _selectedContact; }
            set { _selectedContact = value;}
        }

        public ContactDetailPageVM()
            : base(_navigationService, _auth, _data)
        {

        }

        public override  void OnNavigatedTo(object navigationParameter, Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationMode navigationMode, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(navigationParameter, navigationMode, viewModelState);
            SelectedContact = (Contact)navigationParameter;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any additional details, just asked, I'll be happy to share it with you

Answer (score 1):

The AutoWireViewModelChanged logic is based on a naming convention.

```
/// <summary>
/// The ViewModelLocationProvider class locates the view model for the view that has the AutoWireViewModelChanged attached property set to true.
/// The view model will be located and injected into the view's DataContext. To locate the view, two strategies are used: First the ViewModelLocationProvider
/// will look to see if there is a view model factory registered for that view, if not it will try to infer the view model using a convention based approach.
/// This class also provide methods for registering the view model factories,
/// and also to override the default view model factory and the default view type to view model type resolver.
/// </summary>
```

[ViewModelLocationProvider.cs](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V5/PrismLibrary/Prism.Mvvm/ViewModelLocationProvider.cs)

```
var viewModelName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}ViewModel, {1}", viewName, viewAssemblyName);
```

Make sure that your view models follow the naming convention, e.g. ContactDetailPage**ViewModel**.

Comment: I'm aware of the rules of AutoWire, the naming convention in the project is PageNameVM, and it works for all the other views, don't think the problems comes from the the name. And it still don't explain why the view tries to bind with ProfilePageVM.

edit : to be more precise 

var viewModelTypeName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "ViewModels.{0}VM, ViewModels, Culture=neutral", viewType.Name);

that is the initialization for the name format